# Can I have a NSStackView with draggable separators and resizable views?

Tags: swift, macos

Can I enable draggable separators in a NSStackView, so that I can resize the views inside, by dragging the stackview separators with the mouse?

What I want achieve is: 3 resizable views displayed in a row in the same window.

Comment: Did you consider `NSSplitView` or `NSSplitViewController`? Sounds like they do what you want.

Comment: @OleBegemann Sounds good, I will give a look. Thanks